# Regex to check entry

Tags: regex

I am absolutely terrible at regex and need to know how to determine if a value in a select is either 1 or 2, and not 0.

There are three options and only 2 are valid.

**This is to be used as the validation regex for the jQuery validationEngine plugin.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first off why does it have to be regex?  And 2 show us an example, this sounds like a boolean problem.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, see bold text in question.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question I posed to you.

Comment: Yes it does, take a look at the plugin, did you downvote it?

Comment: I didnt downvote anything.  I moved to close though.

Comment: This is what worked: /^[1-2\ ]+$/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to match the literal strings "1" and "2",

```
/^[12]$/
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to probably just check with `==`, but if you really want to use regex:

```
var regex = /^[12]$/;
```